# how do I read data(object) from params in express?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, express, mean

I am trying to read the object which is being sent as a parameter in delete request.

```
router.delete('/deleteBranch/:id',(req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.params.id); 
});
//What I get
[Object object]
//What I need
{
     schoolId:03746,
     branchId:23231
}
```

I am getting [object object] in console. Instead of that , I want to print the key-values in  console . Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your client(A suppose it's an Angular client), you're passing in the entire branch object instead of just the id

Comment: @Rowland Actually I need both the IDs to make some comparisons

Comment: You can show your client code as well for introspection

Comment: have you tried `(req, res) {`without `=>`?

Comment: @Rowland                                                                            
   `deleteBranch(id){
    this.removeBranch.schoolId = this.currentUrl.id;
    this.removeBranch.branchId = id;
    this.hospitalService.deleteBranch(this.removeBranch).subscribe(data => 
    {
      //
    });
  }`

Comment: @Max Then it wouldn't be a function.

Comment: @Max I have to send a response back to client!!

Comment: Don't know if the error might be in the client code, but I'd try this: `router.delete('/deleteBranch/:id', function (req,res) {` and the response can be between the curly brackets: `console.log();`or `res.send();`...

Comment: It seems like you are trying to post form data using just the URL. `/deleteBranch/:id` is only used when you post to links like `/deleteBranch/123`, then `req.params.id` would be `123`. I'd recommend checking out `body-parser` if you want to post an object.

Comment: What Nelson Yeung said. If you have two pieces of data you want as a url param, you need to send two parameters. I'm wondering why you aren't sending this as part of the body. Then (assuming you are using body-parser) you'd just use req.body to access the object you are sending.

Comment: @Max How the function is created isn't relevant; an ES6 function would work the same as an ES5 function.

Comment: @DaveNewton I just began learning JS, so I'm not used to see pre-ES6 code. Thanks for clearing that out for me.

Comment: @Max The OP's code is ES6 code (arrow function); you suggested changing it to an ES5 function. It's not a big deal, and they're not 100% equivalent (arrow functions bind `this`), but in this case the difference doesn't matter.